# Add cross icon to xaml SearchBox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Is there any way to enable the cross icon on a `SearchBox`?

I'm using this code in my XAML:

```
<SearchBox x:Name="searchBox" Grid.Row="1" Margin="19" PlaceholderText="{Binding Translations.search_searchbar_placeholder}"  SearchHistoryEnabled="False" QueryText="{Binding SearchQuery, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: Since you aren't enabling search history could you not use a `TextBox` instead of the `SearchBox`. The `TextBox` should give you the cross icon without any extra work.

Comment: Thanks @jsmyth886 but when using TextBox I will loose the loop search Icon

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but could you not add the search icon as part of your PlaceholderText?

Comment: Use AutoSuggestBox instead of search box which will give you both things in UWP app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AutoSuggest box instead of SearchBox

```
<AutoSuggestBox PlaceholderText="Search" QueryIcon="Find" Width="200"/>
```

And for any help related to AutoSuggestBox goto this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.AutoSuggestBox)

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I m working on a Win8.1/win10 project, the AutoSuggestBox was not found on the among the xaml types.

Comment: Are you creating win10 uwp app or win 8.1 app because tagged uwp in question so i answered for win 10 uwp , this answer will work in win 10 uwp